# Caliburn CanExecute not working even though firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Trying to implement simple validation with caliburn. All I want is to enable/disable save button based on certain conditions.
View:

```
`<xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="pm_personId" cal:Message.Attach="[Event  LostFocus] = [Action CanSave()]" Mask="00-000-000?"/>
<Button Content="Save" x:Name="Save" />`
```

Model:

```
 public class PersonModel
    {        
        public String personId { get; set; }        

        public PersonModel() {}
        public PersonModel(String id)
        {
            this.id = personId;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class PersonViewModel : Screen
    {
        public PersonModel pm { get; set; }

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            pm = new PersonModel();
        }

        public bool CanSave()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(pm.personId);
            if (pm.personId != null)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }   

    }
```

The MessageBox is fired with the right value but button is not enable. Am I missing anything. Either am missing something with caliburn or it's doing too much magic. Am beginning to suspect that the time it may save you initially will be lost in debugging, just my exeprience.

Comment: Did you review the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @CCamilo but your answer was incomplete. For other people who encounter a similar problem, below is my final working code:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class PersonModel
    {        
        public String personId { get; set; }        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public PersonModel() {}
        public PersonModel(String id)
        {
            this.id = personId;
        }
    }

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class PersonViewModel : Screen
    {
        public PersonModel pm { get; set; }

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            pm = new PersonModel();
            this.pm.PropertyChanged += pm_PropertyChanged;
        }
        void pm_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSave);
        }
        public bool CanSave
        {
            get { return pm.personId != null; }           
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is with CanSave() method.. It should be a property instead:

```
public bool CanSave
{
    get
    {
        if (pm.personId != null)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working either, weird enough though it's fired twice on starting the form.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSave); when the condition changes? for example in the PersonViewModel() ctr

Comment: In any case it should be a property:
http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/introduction